# How to change name of file while creating it in python?

Tags: python, string, uppercase, python-os

I need to take one file and take all of the data and place it into a new file.

I have opened a file in the new directory where all of the new files go. I have it creating a name and doing .upper() for consistency. Then I write the data and close the file.

It then goes and grabs the next file for the same process.
When I look at the files through file explorer, some of the text is capitalized and other parts are not. It is not saving the name as uppercase even though that is what is printing in my terminal.

```
fileNameNoExt = fileNameNoExt.upper()
newFileName = fileNameNoExt + extension

#grabs data
# goes to new directory

newFile = open(newFileName, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
newFile.write(data)
newFile.close()
print("New file created: ", newFileName)
```

Terminal Output:
New file created: JAN2023_HELLOWORLD_DATA.csv

In File explorer: Jan2023_HelloWorld_Data.csv

I have no idea why this is happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: First line of your code initializes variable which you never use in further code, so you can remove it and use `fileNameNoExtPretty.upper()` in second line.

Comment: Where does `fileNameNoExtPretty` come from (notice this is not the same as `fileNameNoExt`)? Did it also get uppercased? Also, if you are on Windows, the file system is case insensitive; so if a file already exists with a different-cased name, it will be overwritten, and not renamed.

Comment: `JAN2023_HELLOWORLD_DATA.csv` I would guess that your code _is_ creating a file named exactly this, in all caps, but in some other directory that you weren't expecting.  In the code, `print(os.getcwd())` to see what directory it is using.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I was not aware that the windows file system is case insensitive, that is why it was not changing. I noticed it was overwriting but not changing the names. Also as Olvin Roght stated, the fileNameNoExtPretty was from a different piece of code I accidentally copied instead of fileNameNoExt. It was supposed to be the fileNameNoExt. It has been edited.